# minicom: AT+CMGR=n not showing the sms content

Tags: linux, sms, at-command, dongle

I'm trying to send and receive SMS via a Huawei e153s USB HSPA Dongle connected to an Ubuntu Laptop. I use a minicom emulator to make the SSH connection. After doing the configurations (setting serial ports, etc.) I tried AT commands one by one.

First I set the modem mode to text mode by `AT+CMGF=1`. When I entered `AT` in terminal then it gives `OK`. After that I successfully sent a message to my mobile using `AT+CMGS="xxxxxxxxxxx"` command but the problem occurs when I tried to read a SMS in the SIM card which I inserted into the dongle. I used `AT+CMGL` but it only shows a OK in terminal 1 (where i opened minicom) and terminal 2 shows

```
T+CMGL
OK
```

and when I use `AT+CMGR=1` it shows OK in terminal 1 and terminal 2 shows

```
T+CMGR1
OK
```

I tried above commands in Ubuntu terminal by using PPP such as

```
chat TIMEOUT 1 "" "AT+CMGF=1" "OK" > /dev/ttyUSB0
chat TIMEOUT 1 "" "AT+CMGR=1" "OK" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and watched the output thruogh another terminal (*terminal 2*) window which shows the file /dev/ttyUSB0 using `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`. (ttyUSB0 is the serial port belongs to the dongle. I returned it through the `wvdialconf`)

but they give the same results as same as previous ones.

Why doesn't that show the content of the message?

Comment: Tip: you can use the [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program to run AT command from the command line: `(echo AT+CMGF=1; echo AT+CMGR=1) | atinout - /dev/ttyUSB0 -`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you first need to select the message storage (`AT+CPMS=XX`), then list messages in that storage (`AT+CMGL="ALL"`), and then when you have a valid index of a message read it (`AT+CMGR=X`).

Have a look at this article: http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/receivesmsat/

Comment: I figured out that the reason to happen above problem is the SMS inbox of the sim is empty. Then I sent a sms to sim card and selected the message storage.then it works fine, thanks...